# Float not working in IE9

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm designing a new newsletter which looks great in Opera, Firefox and Chrome, but somehow, IE(9) messes it up.

Take a look: http://businessgame.be/newsletter.html

The float is not working in IE and the hyperlink of "View last Top 50" doesn't has the correct width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's the float that is messing up. There are scroll bars present only in IE9. This is some kind of over flow problem you are having. Changing the width to something a little bit bigger should fix the problem. IE9 does this thing where it kind of zooms in on your website, making it look bigger on the screen. Try to increase your width and see if that fixes it.

**EDIT:**
By the way, IE9 also has dev tools. Just press F12.

**EDIT 2:**
Yes, I increased your width to 700 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I understand the problem now. What all other browsers do is they take width+paddings+margins = total width. While IE displays it "right" like you expect it. That is, the padding begin part of the width. You can force the browser via CSS to use the IE box model. with the property box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: Yes, I'm going to go read up on that now. Glad I could help with my answer. Thanks

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help, in some way, the width was the problem as you said :).